# No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"waitinglists", :format=>nil, :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters, routes

I'm very new to rails.
and got this error

> No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"waitinglists",
>   :format=>nil, :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]

I know why because I didn"t give :id when I want to redirect , but I don"t know how to give it.

In the index action, I"m not using any forms or link_to stuffs because I just want it to redirect automatically using auto refreshing by time proceeding.

What I want to do is redirect from index to show action.

please tell me how to work it.

**Controllers**

**Waitinglists_controller**

```
class WaitinglistsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate

    def index

        last_group_number = Waitinglist.last.count_number 
        @already_group_people = Waitinglist.where(count_number: last_group_number).count
        @current_person_number = Waitinglist.where(owner_id: current_user.id).last.count_number 
        @current_group_people = Waitinglist.where(count_number: @current_person_number).count 
        current_person_list = current_user.created_waitinglists.last


        redirect_to waitinglists_path if @current_group_people === 4 

            if @already_group_people === 4 
                current_person_list.count_number = last_group_number 
                current_person_list.save
                redirect_to waitinglist_path(@waitinglist, @owner) 

            elsif @already_group_people === 5 
                last_group_number += 1 
                current_person_list.count_number = last_group_number 
                current_person_list.save 
            else
                current_person_list.count_number = last_group_number 
                current_person_list.save
            end
    end

    def new
        @waitinglist = current_user.created_waitinglists.build
    end

    def create
        @waitinglist = current_user.created_waitinglists.build(waitinglist_params)
        if @waitinglist.save
            redirect_to waitinglists_path(@waitinglist, @owner), notice:
        else
            render :new
        end
    end

    def show

        @matched_people = Waitinglist.find(count_number: @current_person_number)

    end 

    def destroy
        @waitnglist = current_user.created_waitinglists.find(params[:id])
        @waitinglist.destroy!
        redirect_to root_path,
    end



    private

    def created_by?(user)
        return false unless user
        owner_id == user.id
    end

    def waitinglist_params
        params.require(:waitinglist).permit(:look_like, :id)
    end
end
```

**application_controller**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception



  helper_method :current_user, :logged_in?

    private

    def current_user
        @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
    end

    def logged_in?
        !!session[:user_id]
    end

    def authenticate
        return if logged_in?
        redirect_to root_path, alert: 
    end

end
```

**Sessions_controller**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

    def create
        user = User.find_or_create_from_auth_hash(request.env['omniauth.auth'])
        session[:user_id] = user.id
        redirect_to root_path,
    end

    def destroy
        reset_session
        redirect_to root_path, 
    end


end
```

**welcome_controller**

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end
```

**Models**

**User.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :created_waitinglists, class_name: 'Waitinglist', foreign_key: :owner_id

    def self.find_or_create_from_auth_hash(auth_hash)
        provider = auth_hash[:provider]
        uid = auth_hash[:uid]
        name = auth_hash[:info][:name]
        image_url = auth_hash[:info][:image]

        User.find_or_create_by(provider: provider, uid: uid) do |user|
            user.nickname = name
            user.image_url = image_url
        end
    end

    def created_by?(user)
        return false unless user
        owner_id == user.id
    end
end
```

**waitinglist.rb**

```
class Waitinglist < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :waiting_person, class_name: 'User'
    after_initialize :set_default_value

  private
  def set_default_value
    self.count_number  ||= 0
  end
end
```

**Views**(only related views)

**index.html.erb**

```
<div class="main">

          <p><%= @current_group_people %></p>


<%= link_to 'cancel', new_waitinglist_path, class: 'btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block', method: :delete, data:  %>

</div>
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<div class="list-group">
<% @matched_people.each do |matched_people| %>
<h4 class="list-group-item-heading">
<%= waiting_person.image_url %>
<%= waiting_person.nickname %>
</h4>
<p class="list-group-item-text">
<%= waitinglist.look_like %>
</p>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: `redirect_to waitinglist_path(@waitinglist, @owner)`, Here you have passed 2 arguments where it requires only one. And what is `@waitinglist` here? I guess, you have missed to define the @waitinglist variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to supply a value to a route helper eg. `waitinglists_path`, just provide it as an argument: so it would be `redirect_to waitinglists_path(@waitinglist)`. `@waitinglist` could be any `Waitinglist` object or an ID. In your code, you would use `redirect_to waitinglists_path(current_person_list)`.

Comment: Thanks so much. I tried it but I got new error message like "Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return"." I"ll try to fix it but do you know how to solve it? @Arvoreniad

Comment: This error occurs when it's theoretically possible for a redirect or render to occur twice in the same action, which is understandably bad. In your code, the first redirect is called if `@current_group_people === 4` and there is a redirect in the first part of the if statement, which is also called if `@current_group_people === 4`. You need to make sure that these cannot both occur, as the entire action code is executed before redirecting. If you can't change it, a `return` should work,

Comment: Oh yes thats totally bad. I really appriciate your help! @Arvoreniad

Comment: No worries, glad to be of assistance.